# What's the relationship between a list and a list of lists?

Tags: python

Say I have **three lists**, as shown below:

```
num = 3

# all numbers in the range 1 to any 'num' with power 2
list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

# split all the elements in list1 into separate lists for every 'num' elements in list1
rows = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]

# rows[0:][i] = columns[i][0:]
columns = [[1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [3, 6, 9]]
```

How would I relate `list1` to `rows` so that `list1[x]` is always equal to `rows[y][z]`?
Likewise, how would I relate `list1` to 'columns' so that `list1[x]` is always equal to `columns[y][z]`?

Comment: I suggest you use [numpy arrays](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array.html). You can then [flatten](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flatten.html) them

Comment: Alternatively, use a single object and provide it with methods to traverse it by column or by row.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `divmod` for that:

```
for x in range(len(list1)):
    y, z = divmod(x, num)
    assert list1[x] == rows[y][z] == columns[z][y]
```

Comment: Hey, that's neat!

Answer (score 0):

For any index `x` in `list1`, you can determine the corresponding indices `y` and `z` in `rows` as follows:

```
y = x // num
z = x % num
```

`num` is a variable that represents a number used for splitting the elements of `list1` into separate sublists in `rows` and `columns`. It determines the size of each sublist. If your matrix is not a square matrix, you can use different `num` values for `y` and `z`.

The floor division operator `//` is used to find the quotient `y` which corresponds to the index of the sublist in `rows`.

The modulo operator `%` is used to find the remainder `z` which corresponds to the index within the sublist in `rows`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of the mod operator and the zip function in python. You would not need to use other libraries in this case, but the built-in python stuff.

```py
list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
rows = [[] for _ in range(3)] # create empty lists for each row

for i, item in enumerate(list1):
    rows[i % 3].append(item)  # add the item to the list using the mod operator

columns = [list(t) for t in zip(*rows)] # using the python zip function to transpose the list

print(columns) # this should output [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
print(rows) # this should output [[1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [3, 6, 9]]
```

Comment: not wrong but not really answering the question...